# Conditions on a relation table n-n

Tags: mysql

I have to create a program in which I have to describe this situation with this relations:

```
City - Country
Country - Language
```

The problem is that I have to create a double-table-relation between City and Country because I have to know in a table the capital of a Country and the other cities have to be in another table.

For instance I have to create a N-N relation with City(Capital) and Country and 1-N relation with City(not capital) and Country. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create an 1-N table between City/Country. then mark certain Cities as Capital.

TABLE `tblCountries`

```
-----------------------
CountryID | CountryName
-----------------------
  1    |   USA
  2    |   South Africa
```

TABLE `tblCities`

```
-----------------------------------------
CityID | CityName | IsCapital | CountryID
-----------------------------------------
  1  |  New York City | 1 | 1
  2  |  Boston        | 0 | 1
  3  |  Johannesburg  | 0 | 2
  4  |  Pretoria      | 1 | 2
  5  |  Cape Town     | 0 | 2
```

`CountryID` and `CityID` are `INT` with `SEED`. `CountryName` and `CityName` are`VARCHAR`, while `IsCapital` is a `BIT`.

Comment: Thank you but I'm looking for a different way to solve this problem.

Comment: What is it that you want to archive really? Because your question will keep getting negative votes as no one knows what it is you want.

Show us the code you have and I will see if I can help you.